# trying to create a directory and saving the audio file

Tags: android

The audio file is not created just after the installation and launching of the app. but from the second time it is creating and my app is running perfectly.
I cannot understand that why the directory is not created at the first time

I have tried all the way i know to create a directory and saving the file. But the directory is not created at the first time.

````
                File.separator + "Ally/");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            // Do something on success
        } else {
            // Do something else on failure
        }


        Random random = new Random();
        AUDIO_FILE_PATH = "/sdcard/Ally/" + random.nextInt(4) + ".3gp";
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)));
        }
        /*
        This code is for getting permissions from Manifest.xml
         */
        Util.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        Util.requestPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder = new AudioRecorder(AUDIO_FILE_PATH, mediaRecorder);```
````

Comment: It was not working as the permissions for record audio and access to media files were not asking simultaneously. but i used a library Dexter to call both the permissions simultaneously and now the application works fine.. Thank you for the support and help.

Answer (score 0):

It was not working as the permissions for record audio and access to media files were not asking simultaneously. but i used a library Dexter to call both the permissions simultaneously and now the application works fine.. Thank you for the support and help.

The url for the Dexter library is:
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter